# How to make a net of nodes in blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, blend-files

How can I make a net of nodes like this:

[image]

Here's the reference video example: https://youtu.be/rTzGMcOd8D0?t=7
I know it's possible by extruding the curves and joining them. But I want to make it quick.

Comment: A curve will not let you connect multiple points together. You need to do this with  a mesh

Comment: You want to make it in Cycles or Blender Internal Render?

Comment: i want to make it only in cycles

Comment: I got the answer from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muJvHClqYi8
That's really nice.
if FasterTutorialsCom are watching this a big thumbs up

Comment: You can generate really cool net type effects with the Animation Nodes addon as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the link @Computer Guy provided solves the problem, but as the link-only answers may become invalid I post a step by step solution how to do it (which uses the *Wireframe Modifier*, *dupliverts/particle system* and *Camera DOF*).
[image]

Create a mesh you want (in my case I use a poor Suzanne again :)) and triangulate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You don't need to do it though if you want to have a quad based wire.
[image]

With the object selected go to the *Modifiers* header and give it a ***Wireframe Modifier***. Set its thickness as you like.
[image]

Select your mesh and give it an *Emission* shader in a *Node Editor* (material). Set its *Strenght* value as you like. Also set the *World* color to pure black.
[image]

Now select your mesh, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*. Add a *Sphere* there (make sure it shares the same origin point as your mesh). Scale it as you want then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Rot&Scale* to apply transformations to it.
[image]

Now select newly added *Sphere*, then your mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Set Parent To*-->*Object*. Select your mesh in *Object Mode* and go to the *Object* header-->*Duplication* panel and press the *Verts* button.
***NOTE:*** You may achieve the similar result using the *Particle System*, but I won't cover it now (maybe I'll edit my answer to explain it later).
[image]

Set a material of a *Sphere* as pictured below (mix an *Emission* and *Transparent* shaders). Play with the *Factor* of a *Mix Shader* to fit the reference.
[image]

With your mesh selected in the *Object Mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to make the duplicated *Spheres* a real/editable objects.
[image]
[image]

Finally select your *Camera*, go to the *Camera Data* header-->*Depth of Field* panel. Use a dropper icon to select one of the spheres that is closest to the camera and increase the camera's *Radius* size a bit. It'll blur the background as in the reference you provided.
[image]

Comment: A good answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

I created an Icosphere, scaled it up, deleted all the edges, duplicated it, and then used this script to connect every vertex to every other vertex:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import sys
# from time import sleep
import time
from math import floor

# wiremess.py
# connects all nodes of an object
# This script is hereby released into the public domain. Feel free to use it in your own project.
# ignore all the commented-out code (:

obj = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

mesh.select_flush(False)

sys.stdout.write("\nWiremess.py\n");

prgpos = 0
prgmax = len(mesh.verts)**2 ## because of looping through all, twice

# while i < len(mesh.verts):
for a in mesh.verts:
    # sys.stdout.write("i: "+str(i)+"\n");
    # while j < len(mesh.verts):
    for b in mesh.verts:
        # a = mesh.verts[i]
        # b = mesh.verts[j]
        if a != b:
            # sys.stdout.write("Connecting "+str(a)+" and "+str(b)+"\n");
            sys.stdout.write("\rProgress: "+str(floor(10000*prgpos/prgmax)/100)+"% ");

            a.select = True
            b.select = True
            mesh.select_flush(True)
            # sys.stdout.write("# of selected verts: "+str(len(
            bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add();
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
            a.select = False
            b.select = False
            mesh.select_flush(False)

            # bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
            # time.sleep(0.3);

            prgpos+=1;
        # }
        # j+=1
    # }
    # i+=1
    # sys.stdout.write("i incremented, now "+str(i)+"\n");
# }
sys.stdout.write("\n"); # to terminate progress meter
sys.stdout.write("Done\n");
```

Then I added a material and set the draw type to Wire.

On the second "icosphere", I created another material and set it to Halo. You can then tweak the colors appropriately.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an IcoSphere. 
It is the best object you can start from.
Go moving the vertices.
Use the K key to create more edges.
And Mesh>>Faces>>wire frame to turn it to lines you can render.
Some Images below...
[image]